# Convert units on rad button click error: System.InvalidCastException

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use radio buttons on a calculator form in VB.net to on click convert from sq cm to sq in and vice versa but when i add the radio button click event to the code i keep getting this error :

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type
>   'Double' is not valid.'

The click event subroutine looks like is this

```
Private Sub radSquareInch_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radSquareInch.CheckedChanged
    txtAnswer.Text = CDbl(txtAnswer.Text) * 0.155
End Sub
```

Comment: It's hard to believe that you even read the error message. You have code that converts a `String` from a `TextBox` to a `Double` and you have an error message that tells you that an empty `String` can't be converted to a `Double`. What do you think that means?

Comment: the string should never be empty though because i enter 0 when the program boots up, how should i change it so that it fixes the problem?

Comment: Perhaps then you need to check the value of txtAnswer is what you expect.  Put a breakpoint in and ensure the value is in fact "0" at run time.  You could even put a if String.IsNullorEmpty(txtAnswer.Text) = String.Empty Then .... before you do your type cast to deal with invaild values

Comment: *"the string should never be empty though"*. Obviously it is, so you need to determine why that's the case. The most likely answer is that you are setting the `Text` of that `TextBox` after the button is checked. We're not the ones with your project and a debugger sitting in front of us though. You are, so debug your project. Either you can change the order in which these things happen, so you would do that, or you can't change them and you need to account for that in the code that uses the data. You can determine which is the case using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

.Net has a great method to check for valid entries in text boxes. It is `.TryParse`. Even if you set `.Text = "0"` in the `Form.Load` you can't prevent the user from deleting it before they click the radio button.

Another problem is using `.CheckedChanged` for the event. A radio button can change from not checked to checked but it can also change from checked to not checked. Assuming that the button is checked will not always get the correct result.

```
Private Sub cmTOin_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmTOin.CheckedChanged
    Dim input As Double
    If Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, input) Then
        If cmTOin.Checked Then
            TextBox2.Text = (input * 0.155).ToString & "sq in"
        ElseIf inTOcm.Checked Then
            TextBox2.Text = (input * 6.452).ToString & "sq cm"
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a radio button")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number.")
    End If
End Sub
```